# List<> and Contains scenario, compare get excluded and included using asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#

I have two List's that contain a object of Tag like List i need to find excluded and included to do an update operation how do find the difference in them both since they contain a Tag object. Can you use Contains function with a Tag object inside the list need some help.

Im using asp.net 2.0 so please if you can help me do it in that language please.

```
List<Tag> tag1 = new List<Tag>()  
tag1.Add(new Tag("Apples"));  
tag1.Add(new Tag("Oranges"));  
tag1.Add(new Tag("Pears"));  

List<Tag> tag2 = new List<Tag>()  
tag2.Add(new Tag("Apples"));  
tag2.Add(new Tag("Bananas"));  

txtExcluded.Text = list1;  
txtIncluded.Text = list2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx):

```
public class Tag : IEquatable<Tag>
{
    public Tag(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Tag other)
    {
        return other != null && string.Equals(Text, other.Text);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Tag);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Text ?? string.Empty).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now the Contains method could work like this:

```
var list = new List<Tag>(new[]
{
    new Tag("Apples"),
    new Tag("Oranges"),
    new Tag("Pears"),
});

var tag = new Tag("Pears");
bool isContains = list.Contains(tag); // returns true
```

Comment: Is IEquatable part of .Net 2.0

Comment: If implementing `IEquatable<T>` you should really also override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` - otherwise chaos follows.

Comment: @kirkdm, `IEquatable<T>` is supported in .NET 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0